What is the best solution for wire to board then board to board connection?
Background: Hello, I am a first timer trying to finish this PCB redesign. I am in dire need as an intern who has no clue what they are doing but is having fun learning.
I have all my schematics working but I need to figure out a solution for this connector scenario in the picture. Someone who is an utter genius hopefully can innovate for me here :D

I need a wire-to-board connector that clamps/secures itself onto the top board's male or female connector somehow.

That male or female connector is connected to the top layer's circuit and then passes it through to the connector below it on the bottom layer.

The bottom board's connector should be able to work without the top layer board by also being able to be used by the same wire-to-board connector that can lock in somehow. (The wire-to-board connection that can snap into top and bottom basically.)

The bottom connectors share the same connection pins and pass it on to the bottom layers circuit. The bottom can work independently or with the top board.

These need to be 10+ pin solutions ideally.


I don't know if this is even possible.

In the left side of the image, the idea is that the two connectors on the top side and bottom side of the top board would be surface mounted and share the same pads or something, (I don't know how to do that, but will cross that bridge when we get there.)

On the right side of the image it's a female with super long pins that then connects to the female connector below.


If any of you can figure this out, I have been at it for a few days, thanks!


Some combination of 0.1" headers with sockets and/or long tails maybe?  What voltages, currents, signals, etc are you working with here?

I have a 24 volt power supply that is coming in and going to be powering a camera and encoder signals are also coming in. The current requirements I have no real clue about. I gotta figure that out as well.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=arduino+shield&iax=images&ia=images

The good news is if you pull this off you'll probably have a good shot at a position since "the person who knows all the connectors" is a pretty important niche spot. The bad news is that's because no one wants to do it!

I am locking in, These are the new clarifications, the wire to board connector has to come in from the side. then the top board to board connection has to then somehow connect to the bottom board to board connection. IF i can find these impossible parts I will be able to speedrun through the rest. the wire to board and board to board connection do not need to latch on to eachother anymore

@Visioncoop new information like this should be edited into your question rather than clarified in the comments - just makes it easier for readability :)

@Visioncoop btw I would recommend going with the idea on the left side of your drawing. They dont have to "share the same pads", you can route the signals from the top layer of your PCB to the bottom layer using vias. Then you would have: one right-angle (from the side) wire-to-board connector on the top. One vertical (from the top/bottom) board-to-board connector on the bottom. The vertical mating connector to that one on the top of the bottom PCB.

@Visioncoop How is this different from your question yesterday? What research have you done? Have you looked at all the connectors in the digikey catalog?

For the connectors needing extra long pins to pass all the way through the board and plug into a board below, use the search term, "Wire Wrap Header". These have extended leads that may suit your purpose.

As for the latches, they are usually on the male connector side. If you mount the female header off the board slightly, you may be able to use "IDC Latching Connectors" on the wire side:


Depends what you mean by "clamping." Both of the ideas commented so far would work as far as I can tell, but if you need latching or locking then go to a site like Digikey or Mouser, search up PCB headers/receptacles, sort by the type of mating you need, number of circuits, etc, and find one that has both a mating board-to-board connector and a mating wire-to-board connector.I cant send you exactly a connector that would work because product recommendations are off-topic here, but I'm sure you'll fine one!

Yeah I need it to latch or lock together, dont know the specific terminology you guys would say. Thank you I will try that right now!!
